# Function ereg_replace() is deprecated - Cannot fix

Tags: php, ereg-replace

I have the above error that I am struggling to fix, the code can be seen below:

```
$anchor = ereg_replace($pattern, '', strtolower($string));
            $pattern = "([[:space:]]|[[:blank:]])+"; 
            $anchor = ereg_replace($pattern, '-', $anchor);
            return $this->short_name($anchor); // return the short filtered name
```

Just to add, I have amended to this:

```
 $anchor = ereg_replace($pattern, '', strtolower($string));
            $pattern = "/([[:space:]]|[[:blank:]])+/"; 
            $anchor = ereg_replace($pattern, '-', $anchor);
            return $this->short_name($anchor); // return the short filtered name
```

But still the error persists and it points to the first and 3rd line as the problem.

Any help appreciated, i have look at other threads and Google but couldnt find the resolution.

Thanks.

Comment: Googling this would've given you many results as well as solutions. All that needed to be done was to so use a starting and ending `/` - `$effort_on_your_part="NULL";` - Plus, did you not bother looking over to the right under **"Related"** >>> - ?

Comment: I cam here as I had tried Googling it but despite multiple amendments I couldnt fix.

Answer (score 0):

[ereg_* functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php) are deprecated user [preg_* functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Don't forget to surround you pattern with delimiters like below.

```
$pattern = "/([[:space:]]|[[:blank:]])+/"; 
$anchor = preg_replace($pattern, '-', $anchor);
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, the error is still showing despite of this amendment.

Comment: You must replace **all** occurrences of ereg_* functions for preg_* functions.